# Capturing Mac OS X System Audio output with Python

Tags: python, audio, macos

I've been trying to "hijack" the Mac OS X system audio using [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) and save to a wav in python. That is, I do not want to record from an input device such as a microphone. I want to grab the sound output from any or all applications.

I have followed the tutorials on the PyAudio site but these do not appear to cover my use case and when I try to read from the output stream I unsurprisingly get the paCanNotReadFromAnOutputOnlyStream exception. Fair enough! Is there a way to do what I am proposing with the PyAudio or other FOSS Python Library?

Comment: If you're willing to install an extra component you can try [Jack OS X](http://www.jackosx.com/) to pipe the input from the source application to PyAudio. In PyAudio you will have to use the "Jack Router" virtual device that will appear as an input audio device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that an open-source project called [SoundFlower](http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/) got me quickly to the place I needed to be.

1. I installed the SoundFlower package from Google Code.
2. Opened System Preferences -> Sound
3. Chose Soundflower as my Output device
4. Chose Soundflower as my Input device

I was then able to record system audio from the default device using PyAudio. No sound comes from the speakers/headphones in this situation though. I wonder if you could use Jack OS X to route audio out of SoundFlower to the system audio out.