# Any way to record audio in python2? (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, audio, audio-recording, voice-recording

I found PyAudio can work in python2 for Windows, Ubuntu. But only work in python3 for Mac.

https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Is that any way to record audio on Mac using python2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing Mac OS X System Audio output with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883090/capturing-mac-os-x-system-audio-output-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

You could give PyJack a look :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/py-jack/

Answer (score 0):

You could try [python-sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/).